# Add PFObject from an NSMutableArray to a new NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, for-loop, parse-platform

My problem is as following:

I run a for-loop in an NSMutableArray that originally were created from a NSMutableDicitonary and add it to another NSMutableDictionary.

How i initialize my Arrays and Dictionaries:

```
activitesPerMonth = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
activitesSeperatedDate = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

self.activityObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
self.gatherAndHoldObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
```

What i do:

```
NSString *stringDayOnly = [dayOnly stringFromDate:selectedDate];
NSLog(@"%d, %d, %d aaand stringdayonly %@", day, month, year, stringDayOnly);

for (PFObject *activity in self.gatherAndHoldObjects){
    activitesSeperatedDate[activity[@"day"]] = activity;
}

NSMutableArray *storeFromDiction = activitesSeperatedDate[stringDayOnly];

self.activityObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:storeFromDiction];
//self.activityObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.gatherAndHoldObjects];
[self.ActivitytableView reloadData];
```

`self.gatherAndHoldObjects` is populated like this:

```
PFQuery *activitesForMonth = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"calendarActivities"];
    [activitesForMonth whereKey:@"month" equalTo:self.displayedMonth];
    [activitesForMonth findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            activitesPerMonth[self.displayedMonth] = objects;
            self.gatherAndHoldObjects = activitesPerMonth[self.displayedMonth];
        }
    }];
```

When i try to populate `self.ActivitytableView` with `self.gatherAndHoldObjects` it works just fine!
but populate the `self.Activitytableview` with `storeFromDiction` i get this error:

> -[PFObject count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14edd940
>
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

What should i do to properly populate `self.ActivityTableview` with `storeFromDiction` to not get the error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line :

`activitesSeperatedDate[activity[@"day"]] = activity;`

assigns a `PFObject` to an entry in your `activitesSeperatedDate` dictionary

and this line

`NSMutableArray *storeFromDiction = activitesSeperatedDate[stringDayOnly];`

retrieves one of those entries and assigns it to an `NSMutableArray` instance. Objective-C will let you do this even though it makes no sense -it will not check that the object assigned to a variable is of the correct type. So you now have an `NSMutableArray` variable which actually contains a `PFObject`. So when you try to treat it as an array (by sending `-count` to it, you get the unrecognized selector error.

Using dictionaries to store your Parse objects with a date as key implies you will only ever have one PFObject per date- dictionaries can only store one item per key. So either use a different form of storage, or make the entries in the dictionary arrays, so you are mapping dates to arrays of `PFObject` - e.g.

```
for (PFObject *activity in self.gatherAndHoldObjects)
{
    NSString *dayKey = activity[@"day"];
    NSMutableArray *objectsForDate = self.activitiesSeparatedByDate[dayKey];
    if(objectsForDate == nil) //instantiate array if it doesn't exist
    {
         objectsForDate = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
         self.activitiesSeparatedByDate[dayKey] = objectsForDate;
    }

    [objectsForDate addObject:activity]
}
```

Comment: What if i add the *activities from the for-loop into an array and then add the array to the dictionary?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Just make sure you don't have any code elsewhere that assumes the objects in the dictionary *are* PFObjects

Comment: just corrected the code I posted, wasn't assigning array to the dictionary entry, also spelling in variable names

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks a lot for your help! Everyday you learn something new about programming ;)

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

U can use forward method invocation or implement one